# Subplots with imshow and suptitle: bad default layout

Tags: python, matplotlib

A very simple example with `subplots` and `imshow` seems to have bad default behavior.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

grid = np.random.rand(2, 4)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.imshow(grid)
ax1.set_title('damped')
ax2.imshow(grid)
ax2.set_title('undamped')
fig.suptitle('Different types of oscillations', fontsize=16)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

Result:

[image]

Why is the `suptitle` so high? Do I really have to manually adjust it every time based on the height of the subplots? A hint about what's going on can be seen by commenting the second `imshow`, though I have no guesses for a solution.

Result:

[image]

The figure is the same size, and seemingly the layout and suptitle etc. are determined based on the empty axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imshow` sets the aspect ratio of your axes to 1, and given your data range that makes the axes wider than they are tall.  If you then put two of them side by side, then there will be blank space above and below the figure.

You can do `imshow(Z, aspect='auto')` as one solution.  If you want the aspect ratio to be 1:1, then you should make the figure wider and/or shorter.

Comment: by the way, there is also `ImageGrid` https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axes_grid1/simple_axesgrid.html